# On openlayer, How to force load tiles for same resolution?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-7

I saw an example of openlayer for preloading low resolution tiles ([Preload.html](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/preload.html))
My code snippet for preload around tile is as follows;

```
....
const myMap = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      preload: Infinity,
      source: <Source of my map...>,
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map1',
  view: view,
});
...
```

But, I want to preload same resolution tiles because i don't want to show changing tiles(from low resolution to same resolution) when camera is moving.

Then, how to force load tiles for 'same resolution', not low resolution?

Is there any api or option for preloading same resolution tiles?
If not, please share code snippet for preloading same resolution tiles.

Comment: You could have a second hidden very large map synchronised with the smaller visible map which loaded tiles for a larger area https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-4wm7tc?file=/main.js  Currently that would be affected by a bug relating to a source with a single cache being controlled by two queues https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14140